# The German consonant "c" changes to the English "g"

Tags: consonants

What is the name of a sound shift law under which the German consonant "c" changes to the English "g", e.g.

Ma**c**ht -> mi**g**ht;
Na**c**ht -> ni**g**ht;
To**c**hter -> dau**g**hter;
fe**c**hten -> fi**g**ht;
re**c**ht -> ri**g**ht;
Li**c**ht -> li**g**ht;
Si**c**ht -> si**g**ht;
Pfli**c**ht -> pli**g**ht;
Fra**c**ht -> frei**g**ht;
Gewi**c**ht -> wei**g**ht;
di**c**ht -> ti**g**ht;
Flu**c**ht -> fli**g**ht;
 
Bu**c**ht -> bi**g**ht

Comment: Sound shift laws apply to sounds, not letters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll notice that all of these words include *ch* in German and *gh* in English. These originally represented the same sound: a *voiceless velar fricative*, written as `/x/` in the International Phonetic Alphabet. (It's the final sound in *lo**ch***, if you pronounce that different from *lock*.)

Both English and German inherited this consonant from Proto-Germanic, where it's written `*h`. (The star is because Proto-Germanic itself was never written down, it's a scholarly reconstruction: `h` is just the letter scholars use when talking about it.) It often came from Proto-Indo-European `*k` through Grimm's Law, though there were other sources as well.

In German, that sound was written *ch*, and has survived pretty much untouched until modern times. In English, however, the sound was written *gh*. And somewhere between Chaucer and Shakespeare, it disappeared entirely: this is called *H-loss* or the *taught-taut merger*.

P.S. Different dialects did different things with the `/x/` when it disappeared. Some turned it into `/f/` after back vowels, which is how we get *laugh* and *tough*. Others lengthened a preceding vowel, which is why *light* has a "long i" sound. Scots still preserves `/x/` even to the modern day.

Comment: using broad transcription to specify the sound is kind of useless here. Given how variable *ch* is in different German phonetic environments, I doubt that it had just one phonetic realization, originally, so there's not much you could do about it. If it helps the questioner, *mächtig* is not fricative in High or Low German at least, though *Macht* is, and that's very regular after *e* or *i* and the umlauts. The vowel alternation is often semantic (as in *drink, drank, drunk*).

Comment: @vectory Hm? I've always heard it /mɛç.tiç/, with not one but two fricatives. Vowel ablaut is of course important in all Germanic languages, but I don't see how that's relevant here.

Comment: So the difference is palatal versus velar, sorry. I'm not too savvy with IPA ... "Macht" is transcribed with an uvular, as is *Dach*, but *Buch* isn't, though it doesn't make a difference for me, personally, and *mächtig* is transcribed with yet a different symbol. This isn't helpful, if the ety of *book* isn't certain. Looking at *machen* (uvular) and *to make*, I feel it should be uvular for *Buch*, too. Maybe you can call *mächtig* fricative. The point is, either there had been just one contrast, then we can have allophones, or there was indeed, also with regional differences

Comment: @vectory As I understand it, the velar `[x]` is used after back vowels, and the palatal `[ç]` after front vowels. I don't think it can ever occur anywhere else. However, I'd always use `/x/` in phonemic transcription, since it's a classic case of complementary distribution. I'd consider using separate symbols a mistake on Wiktionary's part, especially with respect to the uvular (which I've never heard a German-speaker use).

Comment: In Proto-Germanic? Nobody knows. If I look at *Rachen*, OHG hrahhon, ... PIE \*kreg- "to croak, caw", for example, it seems that some instances reflect \*g. I don't see the PGem reflex in Wiktionary, but related En. *retch* links \*hrēkijaną "to clear one's throat" (very apt for the sound that I consider uvular). Since /g/ may be approximated in regional dialects, I think the approximant/fricative distinction may be as important as uvular/velar/palatal, for /x/. After all, it's merely a two way contrast in German. BTW, we have *krächzen*, "croak", which is PGem *krēk-. What's the PIE, \*kreg-?

Comment: @Draconis: In German, the difference is marginally contrastive, because the diminutive suffix *-chen* always has /ç/, and even though this suffix is usually is found after a consonant or a front vowel (historically, it caused ablaut), it is found after the non-ablauted back diphthong *au* in the word *Frauchen* (often cited as an exception to the usual rule of complementary distribution).

Comment: @sumelic Interesting! I do pronounce it `[ç]` there, but hadn't thought of it as a phonemic difference. I'd ask a new question about what happens at other morpheme boundaries, but it would probably get closed as language-specific.

Comment: I think there has been extensive discussion on the topic of [x] vs. [ç] in German, but I don't think there are many other clear examples, since, as I mentioned, *Frauchen* is the main one that I've seen brought up.  This [German SE post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17436) mentions some other examples in *-chen*: *Achen, Tauchen, Kuhchen.* The (rare) words starting in [ç], like *Chemie*, wouldn't change in compounds. Word-final "ch" varies according to context when the preceding vowel is altered by umlaut (which is what I meant to say instead of "ablaut" in my prev comment).

Comment: On the matter of uvular, check this rendition of OG Keemo saying [van Gogh](https://youtu.be/JMtIOQPunJA&t=43s) ("ich konkurier nur mit Mandela und van Gogh") from the throat, rhyming "Loch" (hole, jail) with a velar, which I'd compare to *to lock* (cp. *einlochen* vs *lock-in*), otherwise, by your derivation, *lough* or even *low* (a depression), perhaps cp. *lay low*, "to hide".