# The German vowel “a” changes to the English “i”

Tags: vowels

What is the name of a sound shift law under which the German vowel "a" changes to the English "i", e.g.

M**a**cht -> m**i**ght;
N**a**cht -> n**i**ght

Comment: You seem to have copied the examples from [your other post](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30901/the-german-consonant-c-changes-to-the-english-g) (why from a different account?), but in this question you probably want to highlight the vowels and not the consonants.

Comment: Sound shifts change earlier forms into later ones, but German and English are present-day languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sound changes happen from an ancestor language to a descendant language, not from one modern language to another. However, in this case, German seems to have preserved the vowels from Proto-Germanic pretty faithfully, while English hasn't. So it's still valid to talk about a shift from PGmc `*a` to OE `/i/`.

The key here is called *Anglo-Frisian brightening*: `*a` shifted forward to something like `[æ]` in most environments. In Old English, front vowels then got raised before `/xt/`. This is why vowels before English *ght* are generally higher than before German *cht*: see also *recht~right*, etc.

Post-OE, the `/x/` disappeared and lengthened the vowel in compensation, giving something like `/ni:t/`. The Great Vowel Shift then turned this into modern `/najt/`.

Comment: Could it be the other way around, that the vowel lengthened and the /x/ lost only as a consequence? In that case the question, why the vowel lengthened, would remain. I think it's plausible that way around, given that the German complementary contrast for /x/ depends on vowel color, and consequently length, for which /i:/ is the extreme case (written *ie*, English *ee* as if notably special), and *g* for example goes to /ç/ in Low German after /i:/, too ("wieviel wiecht das?" or even "weycht"), which somewhat explains the *gh* in English, maybe.

Comment: The prime example would of course have to be "Aenglish">English", German "Angel(sachsen)".