# The Proto-Germanic vowel “e” changes to the English “i”

Tags: etymology

What is the name of a sound shift law under which the Proto-Germanic vowel "e" changes to the English "i", e.g.

*f**e**htaną (f**e**chten) -> f**i**ght;
*r**e**htaz (r**e**cht) -> r**i**ght

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [this other answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/30905/10559):

> In Old English, front vowels […] got raised before `/xt/`. This is why vowels before English *ght* are generally higher than before German *cht*: see also *recht~right*, etc.